# How to refresh all virtual tables in HANA?

Tags: hana

I create a stored procedure with a cursor for looping over each virtual table in the system.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "Basis.db::sp_basis_alter_vt_2"( )
   AS
   OBJECT_NAME nvarchar(500);
  
BEGIN
    DECLARE OBJECT_ELEMENT_NAME nvarchar(500);
    DECLARE CURSOR v_Cursor
       FOR SELECT CONCAT(OBJECT_NAME, '"') AS OBJECT_NAME FROM(   
            SELECT CONCAT(OBJECT_NAME, TABLE_NAME) AS OBJECT_NAME FROM(
                    SELECT CONCAT(OBJECT_NAME, '"."') AS OBJECT_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM (
                        SELECT CONCAT('"', SCHEMA_NAME) AS OBJECT_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLES" WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'VT_%')));
    OPEN v_Cursor;
    FETCH v_Cursor into OBJECT_ELEMENT_NAME;
    FOR cur_row AS v_CURSOR DO
        ALTER VIRTUAL TABLE cur_row.OBJECT_NAME REFRESH DEFINITION;
    END FOR;
    CLOSE v_Cursor;
END;
```

The problem currently is, that `cur_row.OBJECT_NAME` isn't recognized as a table entry but as schema name.

How can I refresh all Virtual Tables in HANA Cloud?

Error output is:

```
Could not execute 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "Basis.db::sp_basis_alter_vt_2"( ) AS OBJECT_NAME ...'
Error: (dberror) [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near &quot;REFRESH&quot;: line 15 col 42 (at pos 640)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this solution worked out for me.
Thank you Lars, for your revision!

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "Basis.db::sp_basis_alter_vt_2"( )
   AS
   OBJECT_NAME nvarchar(517);
  
BEGIN
    DECLARE CURSOR virt_tables FOR 
        SELECT 
              '"' || SCHEMA_NAME || '"."' || TABLE_NAME || '"' AS OBJECT_NAME
        FROM 
              "PUBLIC"."TABLES" 
        WHERE 
              TABLE_NAME LIKE 'VT_%';
    
    FOR vtab AS virt_tables DO
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER VIRTUAL TABLE ' || vtab.OBJECT_NAME || ' REFRESH DEFINITION';
    END FOR;
    
END;
```

Comment: I changed a few things to make this code easier to understand. The "CONCAT"/SUBSELECT cascade can be replaced with the `||` concat operator. To loop over the complete cursor, it's easier to use the FOR row AS cursor LOOP. The max size for SCHEMA_NAME (256) + TABLE_NAME (256) + the dot and the four `"` is 517, which is the max size for `OBJECT_NAME`.

Comment: Hi @LarsBr. , thank you for your edit to the solution, works perfectly fine for my colleague. Just saw a syntax issue in the SELECT query before the AS declaration. Needs to be the other way around with the single and double quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks - that's the kind of typo you get when not actually testing the statement. Glad, it works now.